# Running scikit-learn with large volume

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

I need to run a Random Forest process with `scikit-learn`. To train the model, I have a database table with 10 million rows of features. The question is: what is the best way to approach this, should I load into memory the 10 million rows, for example with numpy or pandas or there's a better way to load the data progressively by chunks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872942/sklearn-and-large-datasets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possiblities from dusk, to others model etc.

Here are my 2 favorites, not to loose you in the number of possibilities:

1. [www.h5py.org/](http://www.h5py.org/) "It lets you store huge amounts of numerical data, and easily manipulate that data from NumPy. For example, you can slice into multi-terabyte datasets stored on disk, as if they were real NumPy arrays. Thousands of datasets can be stored in a single file, categorized and tagged however you want."
2. Try online learning with Cousin models of random forest ([light-gbm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453540/how-does-lightgbm-deals-with-incremental-learning-and-concept-drift)). He has online learning capabilities.